# Scene Builder not opening within IntelliJ Idea Community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to open an FXML file using Scene Builder that is within IntelliJ. However, I get an error message despite that I can open the FXML file with Scene Builder alone.

The display only shows this error message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.fxml.LoadListener PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, 192.5728.98] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@7db2b6a4

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader: com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener [Plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX][!
```

[image: IntelliJ error message]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209562).

As a workaround you can try [switching IntelliJ IDEA runtime to version 8](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

Comment: also see that scene builder installation path .give the path in settings

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have found a solution. Just install scenebuilder and open the scenebuilder app. Then open your project .fxml file. Now when u save your work in scenebuilder app, the changes will be saved to your project.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 2019.2 I have the same
[Forum JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004371099-Scene-Builder-does-not-work-anymore-after-update-to-2019-2-version), byt o wersion 2019.1 it still works